# Test Plan/Strategy scenario

Tags: test-management, test-design, strategy

New here. i have this scenario right here as im applying for my first intern position. i really don't understand what to do here. should i make a testplan document etc?

Problem:

1) You're given the task of testing a prototype web application where users can enter a keyword in a web page's Text Field and hit Search. The result is a list of documents that match this keyword (i.e. present as a word in a document).

NOTE: The documents are searched ONLY from a particular backend server hard drive (machine) that is pre-configured in the backend. i.e. based on the machine name in the network, the search will look for all text documents in the main drives of this machine, search inside these documents for the given search query and return the document name (with file path on the machine) to be displayed on the Web UI.

The machine name is set as a key value parameter (e.g. key =  SEARCH_MACHINE_NAME and value can be 'NETWORK_NODE_1')

You can assume that the machine name value is understood by the backend search api program to route the query to the documents on the intended hard drive.

e.g. when the user enters 'ipad' on the TextField, the names of documents (with document file path on the searched machine hard drive) containing 'ipad' as a word will be displayed in a list on the web page, below the text field and search button.

You are told that the Application uses a 3-tier MVC pattern for the development, with a REST'ful Web services API layer sitting in the backend that is servicing the web front end UI request.

Describe how you would design a test strategy/test plan for this application, and then list the test cases that you would execute (manually) with detailed steps before signing off on this application to be used in real time.You are given access to the machines in the backend staging server farm for testing purpose and you can use these machines however you like for testing.

NOTE: State any reasonable assumptions you have made and generate the test plan and cases based on these assumptions. You can list potential assumptions that you would be making, in terms of how this application would be used by users.
And if you have any questions for the product team, you can state that as well, at the end of your test cases."

any overview inputs would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able, you should ask the employer what kind of "test strategy/test plan" he expects, For instance, OpenUP has [a template for test plans](http://sce.uhcl.edu/helm/rationalunifiedprocess/process/artifact/ar_tstpl.htm), but maybe this is not what he expects.

Regarding the test cases, you could try to do [exploratory testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-ItEKt_N_s) over these text requirements, going from the basic acceptance scenarios, as dealing with a few, many, too much, none search results, unexact searches, etc, and try to explore the backend logging system, SQL injection attacks etc.

Answer (score 1):

Especially when the candidate is going to be an intern or new graduate these sorts of questions are usually intended to get an idea of how your mind works when presented with a system to test. Most competent interviewers wouldn't expect the perfect answer or a truly comprehensive set of test cases. Just do your best to be mindful of your stream of thought as you use and analyze the system, takes notes as needed, and clean these up into you test cases.

1. Think about how you can interact with the system. Sometimes this may be as a user (view level) or as another system or tool (model and controller levels).
2. When you interact with these parts of the system what would you look at to determine they did what you expected them to? Is it possible to validate the outcome at more than one level.
3. Spend some time thinking about how you communicate these actions, assertions. Try to be consistent with words and phrases they use to describe the system. It's important your intent can be understood by others or the test case has a limited value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any experience with coding, and debugging/testing your own code?

I am not sure why they expect an intern to have this detailed knowledge, and if they do, and you don't, if you are a **good fit for that internship**.

Don't **setup yourself for a failure by sneaking in by faking the experience you don't have** - how you expect to keep up with the demands of a position for which you lack the skills? How important is for you the evaluation you will get at the end, and what it will say about your skills?

Be honest about your skills, fit internship what is good match for you.